# How to pass function as prop to a child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am wondering if it is possible to send the handleDictionaryResponse and handlePhotosResponse functions as props to the  component

```
function handleDictionaryResponse(response) {
  setData(response.data[0]);
}

function handlePhotosResponse(response) {
  setPhotos(response.data.photos);
}

function handleSearch(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let dictionaryApiUrl = `https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${keyword}`;
  axios.get(dictionaryApiUrl).then(handleDictionaryResponse);

  let photosApiKey = `563492ad6f917000010000010a8428d27f1b43e6bc66cfe662ea13df`;
  let photosApiUrl = `https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=${keyword}&per_page=9`;
  let headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${photosApiKey}` };
  axios.get(photosApiUrl, { headers: headers }).then(handlePhotosResponse);
}

function updateKeywordDetails(event) {
  setKeyword(event.target.value);
}

return (
    <Body property={data} />
  </div>
);
}
```

Comment: There is no component in the code you included. Only a free-floating `return` statement, which in turn holds incomplete HTML/JSX.

Comment: i don't see any hook component !. edit your code.